# Notation $\dot{=}$ Amann's book Linear and quasilinear Parabolic Problems

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, notation

Do someone knows this notation $\dot{=}$? I'm studying Amann's book and he uses this notation but I couldn't find a definition in his book. For example, he writes
$$E_1\cap E_0\dot{=}E_1\ and \ E_0+E_1\dot{=}E_0 \ if \ E_1\hookrightarrow E_0.$$

Comment: "approximately equal to" ? As far as I know. also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equals_sign

Comment: In the abstract evolution equations literature, this is symbol usually means equivalence in the sense of Banach spaces (equal as vector spaces and having equivalent norms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols#Symbols_based_on_equality) it is a symbol used for definitions like $\equiv$ or similar symbols.

Comment: I think that it. He also uses the symbol $:=$, so I believe that it means "is defined as" and as you said $\doteq$ means "is equivalent to ". Thank you.